# Cannot add foreign key constraint - Error

Tags: mysql

I have tried searching for a fix for this error, but haven't got anything yet!
I have written the following query:

```
Create table menuitem (
    itemID int(10) not null auto_increment
  , headerID int(10) not null
  , itemType varchar(45)
  , description varchar(300)
  , price decimal(10,2)
  , primary key(itemID)
  , foreign key(headerID) references menuheader(headerID));
```

> And i get the error - Cannot add foreign key constraint.

The HeaderID field is the same data type as what is there in the Menuitem table, but i still get the error!

Please help. (It might be something very silly i might have missed)

Comment: The menuheader table exist?  .show also the menuheader  table schema

Comment: Yes it does... The menuheader table consists of HeaderID (PK) int(10), menuType varchar(45), description varchar(300)